# How to make apache spark as a windows service?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

i would like to make spark-master always active on windows server.
For now i'm runnung spark-class command, but if I disconnect the service go down.
Looking around I found nothing, has anyone dealt with the problem?